# Why we need the IEqualityComparer,IEqualityComparer<T> interface?

Tags: .net, hashtable, iequalitycomparer

the 'Equal' and 'GetHashcode' method are exist in the object class, and our type inherit the object base class. 
what's the different between implement the two methods of the object directly and using the IComparer interface?

if we overriding object's Equal and GetHashCode , and push to a hashtable , it will use the overring 's equal method?

what' the differents of new a hashtable with the IEqualityComparer constructor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `IComparable` interface is used when you need to be able to "sort" objects, and it gives you a method (`CompareTo`) that tells you if two objects are <, = or > . The constructor that uses `IEqualityComparer` let you give a specific `Equals`/`GetHashCode` that can be different than the ones defined by your object. Normally the `Hashtable` will use your object overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (or the base `object` `Equals` and `GetHashCode`).

To make an example, the standard string compares in case sensitive way (`"A"` != `"a"`), but you could make an `IEqualityComparer` helper class to be able to hash your strings in a case insensitive way. (technically this class is already present in multiple variants: they are called `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` and all the other static methods of `StringComparer` that return a `StringComparer` object that implements the `IComparer`, `IEqualityComparer`, `IComparer<string>`, `IEqualityComparer<string>`)

As a note, the `Hashtable` uses a `IEqualityComparer` optional parameter, not the generic version `IEqualityComparer<T>`, because `Hashtable` is pre-generics.

Answer (score 1):

the `IComparer` interfaces (both the generic and the non-generic one) allow you to compare two instances with each other.

The `Compare` method allows you to compare an object itself with another instance.  Offcourse, when the current instance is null, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` in this case, since you call `Compare` on a 'null' instance.   A class that implements `IComparer` can overcome this problem.

So, when you implement the IComparer interface, you'll have a class which has a 'Compare' method, which can be called like this:

```
public class MyObjectComparer : IComparer<MyObject>
{
    public int Compare( MyObject first, MyObject second )
    {
       // implement logic here to determine whether first is less, greater or equal then second.
    }
}
```

This allows you to do this:

```
var c = new MyObjectComparer();
var one = new MyObject();
var two = new MyObject();
c.Compare (one, two);
```

When you instantiate a `Hashtable` with the constructor where you specify the `IEqualityComparer` instance, this means that the given `IEqualityComparer` will be used to determine whether a certain key is already present in the Hashtable.
Otherwise, the Compare method of the key-object will be used.